# IoC Container Unity is messing with me

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, ioc-container, resolve

There is a possibility I'm not understanding how it's supposed to work.

Where I start my app I do this:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterInstance<IUnityContainer>(container);

//MainWindow
container.RegisterType<Window, MainWindow>();

//Services
container.RegisterType<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();

//Workspaces
container.RegisterType<WorkspaceViewModel, CompanyWorkspace>("Company");
container.RegisterType<WorkspaceViewModel, DivisionWorkspace>("Division")
//More of this
container.RegisterType<IWorkspaceFactory, WorkspaceFactory>();

Window window = container.Resolve<Window>();
window.DataContext = container.Resolve<ViewModel.MainWindowViewModel>();
window.Show();
```

My MainWindowViewModel gets resolved and here is it's constructor

```
public MainWindowViewModel(IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory, IWindowManager windowManager)
    {
        _workspaceFactory = workspaceFactory;
        _windowManager = windowManager;
        _windowManager.Changed += new EventHandler(DialogChanged);
        ControlPanel = new ListCommandsViewModel();
        foreach (string s in _workspaceFactory.GetWorkspaceList())
        {
            ControlPanel.List.Add(new CommandViewModel(s, new RelayCommand<string>(OpenWorkspace)));
        }
    }
```

Notice that I subscribe to a event in the windowManager. WorkspaceFactory and WindowManager should are resolved here by Unity so instances of them are created.

Here is a implmentation of IWorkspaceFactory:

```
public class WorkspaceFactory : IWorkspaceFactory
{
    private IUnityContainer _container;

    public WorkspaceFactory(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public ViewModel.WorkspaceViewModel GetWorkspace(string workspace)
    {
        return _container.Resolve<WorkspaceViewModel>(workspace);
    }

    public ICollection<string> GetWorkspaceList()
    {
        return _container.Registrations.Where(r => r.RegisteredType == typeof(WorkspaceViewModel)).Select(r => r.Name).ToList();
    }

}
```

As I registered the original container as a instance it should be what is passed into the factory. So I'm letting the same Container resolve the workspace that grabs IWindowsManager as a ctro parameter. So it should be getting the sama instance as the MainWindowViewModel got right?

But if I fire off the event from inside the workspace the MainView never gets notified, in actuality the Changed event is empty like this is a seperate instance of IWindowManager.

How may that be?

Am I totally off, I was under the impression that if you don't define a LifeTime for types in containers you alwasy get the same instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but I think you are off - if Unity is like AutoFac then the default behaviour will be "new instance per request".

This is certainly what the docs look like "It will create a new instance of the registered, mapped, or requested type each time" - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc440953.aspx

To correct this, provide a LifetimeManager when you Register the type - e.g. ContainerControlledLifetimeManager (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc440953.aspx)

Comment: Yeah I can see now that I misread the manual. I read the RegisterInstance chapter as it would work on RegisterType. That would explain my problem.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Unity will resolve a new instance for registered types, so you need to register `WorkspaceViewModel` with a different scope. In addition, it's a bad idea to inject the container instead of the real dependencies since it makes it difficult for the client to know what those are.

Comment: I've heard that before. This is mainly just a temp solution as I need to resolve WorkspaceModels based on a string. I'm not familiar enough with Factories that I trust myself to do that just yet.

Comment: Big +1. @Stuart's answer is correct, but I completely agree with @Lee that injecting the container is not best practice. Unity makes it easy to inject factories with Func(T) delegates. See [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ukadc/archive/2010/05/11/unity-2-0-automatic-builders.aspx)

Comment: Nice thank you, I will look into your link later on. I wan't the factory not to be dependent on the Container and pasing in a Delegate might just be the answer.